# Are these two inequalities are equivalent?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, information-theory

Let's assume that $I_j \in \mathcal{J}$, where $\mathcal{J}$ is a set of images that are correctly classified and $p(I)$ is the output probability distribution of the used underlying model. Out of $\mathcal{J}$, we select $\hat{I}_{\!j^*}$ according to a well defined metric according to the inequality shown in (2).

Given that $$\log\left(\sum  p(\hat{I}_{\!j})^2 \right) \leq \sum p(\hat{I}_{\!j}) \log p(\hat{I}_{\!j}) \leq \sum \log p(\hat{I}_{\!j})$$
and
$$
p(\hat{I}_{\!j^*} | y) \leq  p(\hat{I}_{\!j} | y),
$$
where $y$ is the Ground Truth label.

How could we show that the first inequality shown in (1) is equivalent to the second inequality shown in (2)?

$$ \sum p(\hat{I}_{\!j^*})\log p(\hat{I}_{\!j^*}) \leq \sum p(\hat{I}_{\!j}) \log p(\hat{I}_{\!j}) \tag{1} $$
and
$$ \sum \log p(\hat{I}_{\!j^*}) \leq \sum \log p(\hat{I}_{\!j}) \tag{2} $$

Could we make our argument stronger if we mentioned the following?

Both inequalities are equivalent as the log function is a monotonic increasing function and inequality (1) acts as a scaled version of (2), where the sum of the probabilities is multiplied by their respective logarithms.

I have tested it numerically, and both inequalities are equivalent, but I cannot prove it mathematically.

Is this enough? I am planning to build my proof based on this.